# Why does my Haskell program never print to the console?

Tags: haskell, console, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation, console-output

I wanted to practice using the `IO` monad in Haskell so I decided to make a "screensaver" program which would recurse infinitely while printing to the console. When the code runs nothing appears on the console. When I send the `SIGTERM` to the program it prints the hard coded 'proof of concept' `draw` output but no output from the infinite recursion (`go` function).

I suspect this has something to do with lazy evaluation, that the code to output to the console in the `go` function is never called, but I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Haskell Code:**

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust, fromJust)
import System.Random
import System.Console.ANSI
import qualified System.Console.Terminal.Size as Term

data RainDrop a = RainDrop
  { row   :: !a
  , col   :: !a
  , count :: !a
  } deriving (Read,Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  clearScreen
  -- proof that draw works
  c <- applyX 10 draw (return (RainDrop 0 2 10))
  go [return (RainDrop 0 0 10)]

applyX :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyX 0 _ x = x
applyX n f x = applyX (n-1) f (f x)

go :: [IO (RainDrop Int)] -> IO ()
go []     = return ()
go (x:xs) = do
  prng <- newStdGen
  go $ map draw $ maybeAddToQueue prng (x:xs)

maybeAddToQueue :: RandomGen g => g -> [IO (RainDrop Int)] -> [IO (RainDrop Int)]
maybeAddToQueue _    []     = []
maybeAddToQueue prng (x:xs) =
  let
    (noNewDrop, gen0) = randomR (True,False) prng
  in
    if noNewDrop
    then x:xs
    else (
      do
        (colR,gen1) <- randomCol gen0
        return $ RainDrop 0 colR $ fst $ randomLen gen1
      ):x:xs

randomCol :: RandomGen g => g -> IO (Int, g)
randomCol prng = do
  w <- Term.size >>= (\x -> return . Term.width  $ fromJust x)
  return $ randomR (0,(w-1)) prng

randomLen :: RandomGen g => g -> (Int, g)
randomLen = randomR (4,32)

draw :: IO (RainDrop Int) -> IO (RainDrop Int)
draw rain = do
  x    <- rain
  prng <- newStdGen
  setCursorPosition (row x) (col x)
  putChar . toGlyph $ fst $ randomR range prng
  return (RainDrop (succ $ row x) (col x) (count x))

toGlyph x
 | isJust a  = fromJust a
 | otherwise = x
 where a = lookup x dictionary

dictionary =
  let (a,b) = range
  in zip [a..b] encoding

encoding =
  let (a,b) = splitAt 16 katakana
      (c,d) = splitAt 7  b
  in a ++ numbers ++ c ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ d

range    = (' ','~')
katakana = ['･'..'ﾟ']
numbers  = "012Ƹ߈Ƽ6ߖȣ9"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in the `go` function:

```
go $ map draw $ maybeAddToQueue prng (x:xs)
```

doesn't actually execute any of the IO actions - it just creates new IO actions from existing ones.

Here are some type signatures of how I would approach the problem:

```
type World = [Raindrop]

-- draw the raindrops
draw :: World -> IO ()

-- advance the drops
step :: World -> World

-- add more drops
moreRain :: World -> IO (World)

-- the main loop
loop :: World -> IO ()
loop drops = do
  draw drops
  let drops' = step drops
  drops'' <- moreRain drops'
  -- delay for a while here???
  loop drops''
```

Notes:

- I've declared `step` to be a pure function on the assumption that motion of the drops is deterministic
- `moreRain` however needs to use a random number generator, so it is an IO action

Comment: Thank you very much for your design insights. I got it to work mostly. When *not* using `threadDelay` to slow the output, it looks terrible. When using `threadDelay` the output is blocked until `SIGTERM` is sent.

Comment: @awashburn Perhaps you could open another question with your `threadDelay` problem.

Comment: make sure you are not using a buffered handle - or call `hFlush` for every frame

Answer (score 1):

As a rough general rule: `IO` values should usually turn up only to the right of function arrows<sup>1</sup>. I don't know how much you've already read about monads... it might be good to mention that what Haskell does with monads is more [Kleisli arrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category) than anything else, so the typical signature is of the form `A -> M B`, with "pure" `A` and `B`.

That doesn't really answer you question now, but if you refactor your program accordingly (I suppose you want the practise anyway) I suspect it will work, so I'll leave it like this; your code is a bit too expansive for me a afford the time going through it in detail...

---

<sup>1</sup>There are of course exceptions to this rule, in fact some very important ones – generic action combinators, loops etc.. But those are few and already defined in the standard module `Control.Monad`.

Answer (score 0):

`go` takes a list of `IO` actions which are never evaluated, because you never ask them to be. Same for `maybeAddToQueue`. Instead, you probably want to evaluate them as you go.

You are constructing an infinite loop which is supposed to do something. You can probably boil this down to `forever someAction`.

Also, you are doing everything in `IO` so you can use the `IO` versions of the random functions:

```
randomLen :: IO Int
randomLen = randomRIO (4,32)
```

First modify draw:

```
draw :: RainDrop Int -> IO (RainDrop Int)
draw x = do
  setCursorPosition (row x) (col x)
  g <- randomRIO range
  putChar $ toGlyph g
  return (RainDrop (succ $ row x) (col x) (count x))
```

There is no reason for draw to take an `IO RainDrop` because you immediately evaluate it anyways.

```
maybeAddToQueue :: [RainDrop Int] -> IO [RainDrop Int]
maybeAddToQueue [] = return []
maybeAddToQueue xs = do
  noNewDrop <- randomIO 
  if noNewDrop
  then return xs
  else do
        colR <- randomCol 
        len  <- randomLen 
        return $ (RainDrop 0 colR len):xs
```

Finally, your `go` function:

```
go :: [RainDrop Int] -> IO ()
go [] = return ()
go a = do
   b <- maybeAddToQueue a
   c <- mapM draw b
   go c
```

Or, the alternative version, which makes it very clearer what is happening:

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))

go = maybeAddToQueue >=> mapM draw >=> go
```

Note that `map` became `mapM`. This ensures that your actions are indeed being executed. Since the value of the list is never demanded, simply using `map` will never evaluate any element of the list, so none of the `IO` actions were ever being run.